# Word or term for quarter but for 1/5 1/6 and so on?

Tags: vocabulary

Its for a letter to someone. A proposal involving fractals and housing.

Name as much as you can. Im asking for similar terms all in one post because it would probably be useful in the future.

Comment: You mean a fraction?  A portion?

Comment: Quater, quinquies, sexies, septies,  octies, nonies, decies, undecies, duodecies, ...

Comment: @tchrist -- Please!  There are ladies present!

Comment: I edited the tag you used. You were not asking for a single word; instead, you were asking for a list of many words of a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

1/5 is called a 'fifth', 1/6 is called a 'sixth'. I'm sure can work out the rest.

The general term is 'fraction'.